# How can I prevent a stored procedure from running twice at the same time?

Tags: message-queue, amazon-aurora

I'm using an Aurora DB (ie MySQL version 5.6.10) as a queue, and I'm using a stored procedure to pull records out of a table in batches. The sproc works with the following steps...

1. Select the next batch of data into a temptable
2. Write the IDs from the records from the temp table into to a log table
3. Output the records

Once a record has been added to the log, the sproc won't select it again next time it's called, so multiple servers can call this sproc, and both deal with batches of data from the queue without stepping on each others toes.

The sproc runs in a fraction of a second, but my company is now spinning up servers automatically, and these cloned servers are calling the sproc at **exactly** the same time, and the result is the same records are being selected twice

Is there a way I can make this sproc be limited to one call at a time? Ideally, any additional calls should wait until the first call is finished, and then they can run

Unfortunately, I have very little experience working with MySQL, so I'm not really sure where to start. I'd much appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction

Comment: A database is a costly solution to use as a queue. I recommend you use a real queue service instead. Amazon has one: [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/).

Comment: We did consider this, but SQS had some pretty significant costs attached to it as well. 

Thank you for the suggestion though. We might revisit it if our application continues to grow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for [MySQL table locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html).  Try something like this. (You didn't show us your queries so there's a lot of guesswork here.)

```sql
SET autocommit = 0;
LOCK TABLES logtable WRITE;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable AS 
        SELECT whatever FROM whatevertable FOR UPDATE;
INSERT INTO logtable (id) 
          SELECT id FROM temptable;
COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

If more than one connection tries to run this sequence concurrently, one will wait for the other's `UNLOCK TABLES;` to proceed. You say your SP is quick, so probably nobody will notice the short wait.

**Pro tip:** When you have the same timed code running on lots of servers, it's best to put in a short random delay before running the job. That way the shared resources (like your MySQL database) won't get hammered by a whole lot of requests precisely timed to be simultaneous.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like exactly what I was after.